Anaconda evn does not show in VSCode and the interpreter also does not show. If I select interpreter manually, it does not select
This did update my Conda env list. Though after I opened the code by clicking icon, it was back to the problematic state. The envs are correctly shown in the Python venv manager extension, but not in the select interpreter menu. To be exact, just after they show up, they are gone. I could just see a blink of them. I am getting this error from last 6 hr, but it not solve, I also reinstall Anaconda, VS Code, select interpreter by ctrl+shift+p but the interpreter not select, and it also not show in that list.
I check anaconda env show on PyCharm but not show in VS Code.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I reinstall VSCode, Anaconda, reinstall env, reinstall python extension in VS Code, manually the selecting Python interpreter in VS Code, but it did not select

Hello, did you add the path to the anaconda environment to the system environment variables? You can use the conda env list command to view the list of environments. Alternatively, you can try using ctrl+shift+p to select the interpreter and then Enter Interpreter path.
